# Applying CSS only to parent without touching the child

Tags: html, css

How can I hide/remove the "Category:" text here without touching what is inside `<span> </span>`?

```
<h1 class="f_p f_700 f_size_50 w_color l_height50 mb_20">
Category:
<span>Men</span>
</h1>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you help me understand why "Category" shouldn't display? Is it for screen readers?

Comment: Basically it's coming with WP category pages by default and it's unnecessary for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I missed the important detail below. As another answer might have noticed, trying something like `display: none` and `display: initial` isn't going to work.

> How can I hide/remove the "Category:" text

---

The [initial CSS keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) can be applied to children to reset styles. As the doc mentions, sometimes `initial` has unexpected results, check out its peers `inherit`, `unset`, and `revert`. To give an example using text color:

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}

h1 > span {
  color: initial;
  visibility: initial;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="f_p f_700 f_size_50 w_color l_height50 mb_20">
Category:
<span>Men</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change visibility to hidden or font-size to zero on parent and reset it on the child. Without attaching any styles to the child, it's not possible with css.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to use JS, try this:

```js
$("h1").contents().filter(function(){
    return (this.nodeType == 3);
}).remove();
```

```html
<h1>Category:<span>Men</span></h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, with CSS only:

```css
h1 {
 font-size: 0px;
 visibility: hidden;
}

h1 span { 
 font-size: 36px;
 visibility: initial;
}
```

```html
<h1>Category:<span>Men</span></h1>
```